# SQL Query in Access not applying WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am an amateur vba programmer currently struggling with the following:

I wrote a simple SQL Query for my VBA program to extract data from an existing Query (GroupedData) in Access:

```
Dim strSQL as string
Dim db as dao.database
dim rs as dao.recordset

strSQL = "SELECT GroupedData.EmployeeID, GroupedData.End, GroupedData.LOB, GroupedData.Position, GroupedData.WorkStatus " & _
    "FROM GroupedData WHERE (((GroupedData.End) Is Null) AND ((GroupedData.Position)=0) AND ((GroupedData.WorkStatus)=0));"

Set db = OpenDatabase(MY_DB, dbOpenDynaset)
Set rs = db.openrecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    ListBox1.AddItem rs!EmployeeID
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

So my problem is that SQL is running smoothly but is not applying any filters (that is where clause - it produces records where workstatus and position contain values above 0)

I have done such queries in the past without having any issues. This time however I am stuck

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Please remove all the brackets from your WHERE clause. Also, look into aliases, they will shorten your code and make it more readable. Like that: `SELECT gd.EmployeeID FROM GroupedData gd`

Comment: Apart from the cosmetics, the query should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your tips but after getting rid of the brackets the code is still not producing the right results. If I paste this code into access it works brilliantly

Comment: Just for kicks, clear the listbox before adding records.  If the problem isn't your query (and it doesn't seem to be) then maybe the issue is that you have somewhere else that also populates the listbox.

Comment: Double checked and ran the code line by line. This is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have fixed the issue. Here is what happened:
I have made a separate function that was retrieving Employee Name based on EmployeeID. But in that function i had recordset and database declared the same way, that is: rs and db. What happened when i ran the query was it was taking the first record filtered but then the rest of them were unfiltered because they were based on the recordset within the function (which is of course all of the employees) Such a silly mistake :) Thanks anyways